# Enter page that you have to be logged in

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I need To send get request To page that I have to login first

**using `requests module`**

I tried to first send post request and make login with my information

Then using cookies which is [phpsessionid] & send it with the get request

```
cookie = {'PHPSESSID': 'm7v485i9g1rfm3tqcn0aa531rvjf5d26'}

 x = requests.get('https://www.example.com/',cookies=cookie)
```

but it doesn't work !

And idea on how to open the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to hijack a session, login using `requests` with something like:

```
session = requests.session()
session.post(loginUrl, data={'username':username, 'password':password, ... (anything else the login page posts)}
response = session.get(anyInternalPage)
```

Comment: it works thanks :) ,.  But can you tell me what's the problem in my code or in my way ?

Comment: Your method is trying to hijack a session, and most servers have code to prevent people from doing that. This is because you could potentially do this in a very malicious way.